# Should I use a composite key in a FK relationship, or the parent table?

Tags: sql-server

Simple question, but not sure of a better or more technical way to title it.

Three tables:

1. tbl_House (HouseID PK)
2. tbl_HouseLike (HouseID PK, UserID PK) <-- composite key
3. tbl_HouseLikeNotify (HouseID PK, UserID PK) <-- composite key

To explain the above, someone clicks **like** on a house profile, which is inserted into the tbl_HouseLike and tbl_HouseLikeNotify table.

A process checks this 3rd table every so often and sends out notifications to the home owner, and when it's done, it just deletes the record from the 3rd (notify) table. It basically serves as a temporary space, not intended to store long-term critical data.

If a house is deleted from tbl_House, I'm using **on delete cascade** on tbl_HouseLike to delete the related record.

Question is, what is the best way to handle the 3rd table?

### Option 1

Add a FK for tbl_HouseLikeNotify.HouseID references tbl_House.HouseID
If I did this, I'd have to delete from the tbl_HouseLikeNotify table in my stored procedure if a record was delete from the tbl_HouseLike.

### Option 2

Add FK for (tbl_HouseLikeNotify.HouseID, tbl_HouseLikeNotify.UserID) references (tbl_HouseLike.HouseID, tbl_HouseLike.UserID)

So are there any pros or cons to referencing the composite key vs referencing the parent table? I do like cascading, regardless of the arguments, and by doing this, if someone "unliked" a house before a notification is sent out, it would cascade and delete from both the tbl_HouseLike and tbl_HouseLikeNotify. Otherwise, I'd have to delete it in my stored procedure.

Comment: Why the vote for close? I'm not sure if it's better to set the relationship between the composite keys or the parent table, or what implications (pros/cons) that might have. How can I improve my question?

Comment: In Past Composite key have give me trouble with the Update and Insert table triggers. therefore i use single column PK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless only one user is allowed to create a notification to the homeowner at any time, then you have to choose option 2, because you could have multiple persons having interest in the same house during the same interval between notification checks.

Option 2, relying on the **cascade delete** rule, would offer less code to have to write, test and maintain. However, if you only want the owner to receive only one notification over any interval, you would have some work to do to enforce this limit. You would also want to document this fact, because the option 2 design would allow multiple pending notifications on the same house.

Comment: It'll actually query and grab all notifications for any given scenario, so it's sent in one email. So no issues on setting up a FK between two sets of composite keys? performance?

Comment: You have the actual work of having the engine perform the chained deletions, but you would have that anyway, whether you implement that as a __cascade delete__ rule or write t-sql to explicitly perform it. As far as the FKs having sets of composite keys, I have seen it done elsewhere.